# Windows utility to display and pick accented characters?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, special-characters

There seems to be no port of the iPhone/Android feature that displays a list of accented characters:

[image]

Currently, even using the right keyboard layout, users either have to use the ALT key to enter the right ANSI code (eg. É = ALT + 0201), or limit themselves to applications (Word, etc.) that performs auto-correction.

As a result, people often type without using those accented characters when they really should.

Is there really no utility available that works the same way?

Comment: Win+R `Charmap`

Comment: Not as easy to use as an IME for Far-East languages, which provide an in-place solution: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC80094.gif

Answer (score 1):

Character Map, its under Accessories somewhere, or un "charmap" from Run. Its been in windows for about 20 years (Since windows 3.0, at least). I use it for scientific symbols.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map

Comment: It's nowhere as fast and easy to use as Android. Charmap is only good if you don't need to use European languages on a daily basis.